# Javascript - Get Array of Inputs From Form

Tags: javascript, forms, function

I'm trying to make a universal "Check Empty" javascript function. What I figured I would do was onsubmit get the number of `input` boxes in the form and take it's length like so:

**I did pass the form name into the function via `this.name` and called it `formVar`**

```
var len = formVar.input[].value;
```

Then I would use that variable as a limit to a loop so I could check each one and see if it was empty. What's the problem with the above code snippet? Is there a way to get a number of inputs in a form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kmWwa/)

`input[]` isn't a valid identifier in JavaScript, so you'll need to access these inputs as a string index on your form:

```
var allInputs = formVar["input[]"];
var len = allInputs.length;
var anyChecked = false;

for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
   if (allInputs[i].checked){
      anyChecked = true;
      break;
   }

if (!anyChecked) 
    alert("all checkboxes are empty!");
```

Comment: Nice! I guess `input[]` returns a number which populates `formVar `array? I don't quite get how that works :S

Comment: `formVar["input[]"]` returns a collection of dom elements.  In this case, those inputs with a name of "input[]"

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following to figure out the number of input elements in your form:

```
document.forms['search'].getElementsByTagName('input').length
```

this assumes you have a form named search. or you can use your `formVar` to replace `dcoument.forms['search']` part